# Render A file result in a new Tab in Blazor

Tags: blazor, webassembly

In my blazor client component I get the report using this:

```
<button @onclick="GetReport"> GET</button>

    protected async Task GetReport()
    {
        var dateFrom = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
        var dateTo = dateFrom.AddDays(1);
        var parameter = new FetchEmployeeAttendance
        {
            DateFrom = dateFrom,
            DateTo = dateTo,
            ReportType = 1,
            UserId = 2
        };
        var result = await DailyTimeInService.GetDailyAttendances(parameter);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

In the service, this is how I call the server:

```
public async Task<System.Net.Http.HttpContent> GetDailyAttendances(FetchEmployeeAttendance parameter)
    {
         var result = await httpService.Post($@"api/Reports", parameter);
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<HttpContent> Post(string uri, object value)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
        var x = JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await SendRequest(request);
        return result;
    }

    private async Task<HttpContent> SendRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var user = await localStorageService.GetItem<string>("access_token");
        var isApiUrl = !request.RequestUri.IsAbsoluteUri;
        if (user != null && isApiUrl)
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", user);

        using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(content);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("login");
        }

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            var reply = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var oReply = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ErrorReply>(reply);
            await helperService.InvokeAlert("Sorry...", $@"{oReply.Error[0].ToString()}", true);
        }
        return response.Content;
    }

In the server, this is the controller that I call:

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetReportByAdmin(FetchEmployeeAttendance parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await repo.GetDailyAttendances(parameter);
            string mimeType = "";
            int extension = 1;
            var path = $@"{webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\Report.rdlc";

            Dictionary<string, string> param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            param.Add("param", "Sample Report");
            var localReport = new LocalReport(path);
            localReport.AddDataSource("dsAttendance", result);
            if(parameter.ReportType == 1)
            {
                var res = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, param, mimeType);
                return File(res.MainStream, "application/pdf");
            } else
            {
                var res = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Excel, extension, param, mimeType);
                return File(res.MainStream, "application/msexcel");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return apiResult.Send400(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The reply from the server could be in pdf or excel form. How do I render the file(pdf or excel) in a new tab since I am not using the "href" attribute in the component because I need to include some parameters on my server call?

Comment: Parsing a pdf file is extremely difficult to do well on the web.  I'd recommend using a pdf C# library to render it to .jpg, and then present those as sources for an <img> tag.  Excel is slightly easier depending on exactly what you need.  IF you just need the tabulated data, that's pretty easy.  If you need the exact APPEARANCE, then that will be very hard.  Even the desktop and online versions provided by Microsoft do not match the formatting reliably, so I'd imagine (no offense) that it would be even harder for you.

Comment: Another option is to find an SVG converter or save option for either, as SVG is much more compatible with the web experience.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Thanks. What I just did was to retrieve the List from the API, then in my Blazor WASM, I just converted it to pdf and excel. So the client side is rendering it as pdf and excel. It became a LOT, easier.

Comment: Well, the problem is that not all client sides are guaranteed to be capable of rendering pdf or excel documents.  But if you have results you're happy with, I'm happy to hear it!